# How to remotely execute a bash script with an option?

Tags: bash, redirect, ssh

I am attempting to remotely execute a Bash script defined as `$CONST_FILE` while passing an option to it (in this case `-u`). Unfortunately for me, the Bash Interpreter assigns my option to ssh instead my script; causing an error as ssh does not have a `-u` option.  The below section of code is causing a problem for me:

`(ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l $CONST_USERNAME $HOST_NAME_LOGIN<$CONST_FILE -u)`

In previous Bash scripts, I have been able to execute Bash scripts via the above method so long as I was not passing an option with the script I was attempting to execute.

I have tried various placements of `{} "" '' []` and other characters without success. What set of characters do I need in order for the Bash Interpreter to understand that `-u` needs to be consumed by `$CONST_FILE` instead of ssh?

Comment: Have you tried putting quotes around your command? as : **ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l "$CONST_USERNAME $HOST_NAME_LOGIN<$CONST_FILE -u"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is to use command like this:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l $CONST_USERNAME $HOST_NAME_LOGIN "$CONST_FILE -u"
```

You can use also format like:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ${CONST_USERNAME}@${HOST_NAME_LOGIN} "$CONST_FILE -u"
```